# MVC allows an XSS attack when using an API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xss

I'm making a ASP.NET MVC Web application and I'll send some data to it using an API call with following content.

```json
{
    "content": "<script>alert('hallo');</script>",
    "title": "<script>alert('hallo');</script>"
}
```

How can I prevent that this is accepted by the server? I know that XSS is prevented in MVC by default but it seems not to work. This is my code on server side:

```cs
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create()
    {
        // ...skipped
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your server accepting that.

Comment: Following from @SLaks, the problem is if you include that information verbatim into something you send to the browser.  If the data is untrusted (as this should *absolutely* be), then you need to `HtmlEncode` it before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats all ok.
your server should accept it.

usual pattern for this is:

- accept things from client as they are sent
- do html entities encoding for everything you send back to client